# Overlaying row menu in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display a row menu at the end of the row (aligned on the right and overlaying the content of the row):

1. When the user hovers a row, the row menu should overlay the row.
2. When the user clicks a row, the row menu should be encrusted in the row.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/etbsf3n8/6

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Type of content</th>
      <th>Content with menu</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-menu">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>Table</td>
        <td>
          <div class="table-menu">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="button" class="btn disabled btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Shape</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ball</td>
                    <td>$5</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cube</td>
                    <td>$2</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Inline</td>
      <td>
          <div class="table-menu">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline;background:red;">Red</div>
          <div style="display:inline;background:orange;">Orange</div>
          <div style="display:inline;background:yellow;">Yellow</div>
          <div style="display:inline;background:green;">Green</div>
          <div style="display:inline;background:blue;">Blue</div>
          <div style="display:inline;background:violet;">Violet</div>
          <div style="display:inline;">What what ?</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>Inline-block</td>
      <td>
          <div class="table-menu">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="button" class="btn disabled btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline-block;background:#fee;">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline-block;background:#efe;">
              In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "tr", function() {
    var row$ = $(this);
    if (isActivableMenu(row$)){
        activeMenu(row$, !isMenuActived(row$))
    }
});

$(document.body).on("click", ".table-menu", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

function activeMenu(row, value) {
    var row$ = $(row);
    var menu$ = $(row$.find(".table-menu"));
    if (value){
        row$.addClass("active");
        menu$.addClass("table-menu-active");
    }
    else
    {
        row$.removeClass("active");
        menu$.removeClass("table-menu-active");
    }
}

function isMenuActived(row$) {
    return $(row$).find(".table-menu-active").length > 0;
}

function isActivableMenu(row$) {
    return $(row$).find(".table-menu").length > 0;
}
```

CSS:

```
.table-menu
{
    display: none;
}

tr:hover td .table-menu, tr:hover th .table-menu
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.table-menu-active
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

My problem is on rows #2 and #4. The row menu doesn't overlay the row content, but is on top of it.

How can I create an menu overlaying the content of the row ?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/etbsf3n8/7/) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/etbsf3n8/7/)

I have changed your **CSS** a little bit as follows

```
tr:hover td .table-menu, tr:hover th .table-menu {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Used `position:absolute;` with `right:0;` and `top:0;` which made it to appear as an overlay at the top right.

**UPDATE**

To make the the absolute positioned div always stick to the left of the table, I added the below CSS

```
.table{ position:relative; }
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/etbsf3n8/11/)

Comment: With the "right:0" attribute, the row menu will be aligned on the right of the page, not on the right of the table. See the problem in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/etbsf3n8/9

Comment: Then you can use `position: absolute;` without `right: 0;`..see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/etbsf3n8/10/)

Comment: Indeed, but the row menu is aligned on the left of the cell, not on the right. Maybe should I use java script to set the right attribute.

Comment: You dont need to...see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/etbsf3n8/11/)..Is this what you need?

Comment: With `.table{ position:relative; }`, it works. Thanks !

Comment: [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/etbsf3n8/11) an acceptable script for interested people.